# Quel est le mot dans la seconde partie de cette fiche audio?

Tags: vocabulaire

[La deuxième partie](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KfeTssC8t4ImUu806hzeoyOQkAK6YjxF)
« Orace un, ___ de onze» ? Et « orace », qu'est-ce que c'est? 
Après que la question est resolúe, quelque contexte:
*L'Ordre du Temps*, livre par Carlo Rovelli:

> "La citation est juste une substance poétique typique que je n'ai pas besoin de comprendre. Les paroles que nous venons de prononcer, Le temps, dans son vol, les
>   a déjà emportées, et rien ne revient. (I, 11)"

Comment: C'est le genre de question qui ne sont pas les bienvenues sur FL. Malgré le manque de contexte, je suppose qu'il s'agit de « Horace 1 Ode 11. »

Comment: Qu'est-ce que vous appelez l'ordre de temps ?

Comment: @LPH Un texte de physique. -édité

Comment: La citation se trouve dans le livre de physique et vous cherchez à comprendre ce que Rovelli apporte à la notion de temps physique en citant Horace ?

Comment: @LPH non, je n'avais aucune idée de ce que le mot était parce qu'il est lu dans le livre audio mais pas écrit. La citation est juste une substance poétique typique que je n'ai pas besoin de comprendre. Signifie probablement juste que le temps est déconcertant mais qui sait.

Comment: Ce livre utilise des mots étrange comme "Hommes-sandwich" pour panneau

Comment: Qu'est-ce donc que vous demandez dans cette seconde partie de votre question ? Essayez d'être précis, autrement on ne peut rien répondre.

Comment: vous avez déjà répondu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit d'**Horace**, le [poète latin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horace) et d'une de ses **odes**, l'ode numéro 11 ([Odes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horace)). « Un » réfère au premier des quatre livres.

Answer (score 1):

Horace, un, ode onze.

Horace, c'est le poète latin.  Un fait référence au livre un sur les quatre livres d'odes qu'il a composées.  Ode 11, onzième ode ou poème du livre en question.